# Can't embed ACE Editor "ui-ace need ace to work" error with angular-ui-ace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ui, ace-editor

I'm trying to embed [ACE editor elements](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace) into my AngularJS project in order to allow JSON editing feature in it. Here are all configurations/settings so far:

**Bower.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular-ui-ace": "v0.2.3"
}
```

**Module dependency**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.ace']);
```

**ACE settings in controller**

```
$scope.ace_options = {
  useWrapMode : false,
  showGutter: true,
  mode: 'json',
  onLoad: function() {
    console.log('onLoad fired.');
  },
  onChange: function() {
    console.log('onChange fired.');
  }
};
```

**Html**

```
<div id="editor" ui-ace="ace_options" ng-model="myJson" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

However I get always following error:

> "message": "Error: ui-ace need ace to work... (o rly?)",

What I'm doing wrong or did I missed something?

Comment: Does this asset exist in the bower_components folder? bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js... Moreover, do you have a script linking to it in your HTML? `<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>`

Comment: @ThisClark, Yes, bower_components folder has **ace-builds** folder and files since it will be loaded along with angular-ui-ace library as dependencies.

Comment: So, got it. You was right regarding **ace.js** link in html. Somehow its not there. Is this problem from ace library or one should include it manually?

Comment: No, it's not a problem with the library. One should include it manually in proper order according to the documentation. Ace, Angular, and Ace UI are three separate concerns, so the scripts are developed independently of one another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetching the scripts with Bower, make sure you include them in your application. Following is the order of scripts provided in the [Ace UI docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/ace-builds/src-min-noconflict/ace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-ace/ui-ace.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get ui-ace working by adding ace.js from a CDN in my header:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.6/ace.js"></script>`

I use require to include npm modules but had a little trouble including ace via require so I just added it manually as an HTML header include.

It was also necessary to add a style="height: 400px;" to my ui-ace div to make it visible.